# How can I hide a page in FastReport?

Tags: fastreport

When I enter a boolean Parameter [ByIssueDate] into the "VisibleExpression" field on Page1 properties, it's ignored and the value from the "Visible" field is taken instead, no matter if the ByIssueDate parameter is true or false.

I was expecting, that the "VisibleExpression" will override the "Visible"

Version: FastReport.Net Version 2021.4.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign the boolean parameter in Page1.OnBeforePrint event.
Anyway, look here:

https://forum.fast-report.com/en/discussion/583/how-to-hide-pages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).